# Changing image scale MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab

I have a image that I am trying to read via `imread` but after reading the image it comes to a matrix of 256 x 256 x 4 but to work on it i need it to be 256 x 256 x 3. I am trying but I am unable. So how can I try to convert it?

```
im = imread('Test1.tif');
```

Comment: It will help if you can give a link to the actual image and show the code you use to read it ...

Comment: @Hoki
>> im = imread('Test1.tif');
>> map(im);

link to image: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/XeKcERYiIVdClrHbmlt26ApTNgdyOUefG0d5r4ewlWout8AuVaiJ4zEwDkww6BN9WEVwbg=s129

Comment: `im=im(:,:,1:3)` ?

Comment: This is likely an RGBA tiff. The fourth channel (`im(:,:,4)` is likely the alpha (transparency) channel). If there is no transparency, you can safely do what @AnderBiguri has recommended.

Comment: You should include these info in the original question (edit it) instead of putting them in comments. The image you share is `jpg` while you are reading a `tiff` file. As Suever mentioned, it may be because the image you are reading has a transparency channel (alpha value), hence the added layer. just identify which layer is the transparency one then get rid of it using @AnderBiguri's comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always a good idea to inspect the output of imfinfo whenever you're not sure about an image format...

If you carefully read the documentation of the imread function regarding TIFF images:

> If the color image uses the CMYK color space, A is an m-by-n-by-4 array. To determine which color space is used, use imfinfo to get information about the graphics file and look at the value of the PhotometricInterpretation field.